# How Can I Detect the OS Version in Go?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, go

I'm currently writing a REST API client, and I'm trying to determine what OS the user is using in order to generate a useful User Agent string. This is going to allow me to (hopefully) make good decisions about what OS's I should bother supporting in the future.

What I'd like to do is this: generate a string that looks something like:

Linux/1.3.2 OR Darwin/1.3.2 OR Windows/1.3.2

It should work across Linux / Mac / Windows.

Currently, I'm able to retrieve the OS type (eg: 'linux' / 'windows' / 'darwin') using

```
runtime.GOOS
```

But I'm unable to find a way to grab the OS major/minor/micro versions.

Comment: Why do you care about the exact OS version?

Comment: This is an API client library that's going to be (eventually) used by a lot of developers worldwide, so I'd like to be able to know what OS versions to support / invest in. EG: Maybe I end up with a big userbase of Windows developers, and want to expand my Windows client support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the extensive discussion in [Go google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/NzEPGqlHIYQ) it looks like nothing reliable exists. I still suggest you to take a look at the discussion, as there are some useful ideas how to extract some information for particular OS.

**P.S.** does not the browser send this information in User_Agent?

```
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: This is being used in an API client library -- so I can't use browser agent stuff :(

Answer (score 1):

Use [uname](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Uname) (for the [uname(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/uname.2.html) syscall), which should be available on POSIX systems like Linux & MacOSX.

I don't understand why you need such precise information; BTW, on Linux, and probably MacOSX, it is in not enough, the version of the [libc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) (and of course, of the GO runtime) matters at least as much.

<sup>(You should find something similar for Windows if you care)</sup>

Comment: Most Posix systems have `uname` as a library routine, not a syscall (and therefore not in the syscall package). However, cgo can be used to call uname (and `C.struct_utsname` is more directly usable than how the Linux syscall and golang.org/x/sys/unix packages define `syscall.Utsname`).